# (Issue) Unusual ads on HTTP websites

Tags: tls, http, injection

Most of the things written here is based on my current knowledge of networking, Any kind of help would be appreciated.

I am facing an issue regarding ads on websites not secured with HTTPS (this is my observation). To support my point, i have added images from couple of HTTP websites.

[image: first]

[image: second]

Further information, this problem is **browser independent** (getting same problem in safari). **Ad Blocker** is not working.

My Questions,

1. Is there any way to stop these ads or not?
2. If yes, then please guide me to eradicate these ads.
   Again, all of the provided information is based on my current knowledge.

I am not an expert in networking, so i can only blame security of HTTP websites.

If you require furthermore information or clarity, let me know by writing comments. If this type of question has already been asked, then provide me the link and I need to work on my googling skills.

**edit**: This problem is not specific to my laptop, These ads are coming on other computers connected to my wifi network.

**edit2**: I came to know that these ads are coming on other wifi networks too provided by my ISP.

Comment: My guess is that you are infected by an ad-injecting malware. Details are unknown and thus fixes are unknown too but it might be for example the recent surfaced "OSX/MaMi" malware - see https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/ay-mami-new-dns-hijacking-mac-malware-discovered/. In general you might follow public available instructions to detect and remove such malware, for example this one: https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-mac-os-x-virus/

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for your reply. Can you help me to suggest any good anti-malware that can detect this malware. I tried MalwareBytes and it said you are clean.

Comment: First, product recommendations are off-topic here. And, it is not even clear if this is a malware on your computer or if your router is infected (see https://thehackernews.com/2016/12/dnschanger-router-malware.html). In this case a local malware scanner will probably find nothing.

Comment: It could be a network adding to the page deliberately, which would explain only http being affected

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, These ads are showing on other computers too that are connected to my wifi network, Does it mean my router is infected?

Comment: It might even be a really bad ISP. Those could be the hardest to change.

Comment: @JohnDvorak, if you know any solution to this problem, Please guide me to resolve this problem.

Comment: @GauravSharma: It is very likely then that either your router is infected or your ISP is running some side business by injecting ads. While the last one happens sometimes the first one is more likely. In this case - reset the router, update the firmware so that it does not get infected in the future, change the password or if no updates are available get a new device. Check out https://routersecurity.org/ for more help and for devices which are known to have problems.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: Thanks you very much for your guidance. First, I want to confirm second scenario and let you guys know by updating the post.

Comment: These ads are coming on other wifi networks provided by my ISP. So I need to talk to my ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this happens:

- on HTTP websites but not HTTPS
- across different browsers and even devices

then this is not an ad-injecting malware but your ISP injecting ads of his own. How to deal with this was explained before, [on a different site though](https://superuser.com/questions/902635/isp-is-inserting-ads-into-web-pages):

- Only use HTTPS Web sites, make sure you enter "https:" while manually typing in a URL;
- Set up VPN connections on your devices, or better, on your Wi-Fi router, so that all your traffic would go encrypted through the offending ISP's network. In some cases, given a proper Wi-Fi device, you might be able even to route only HTTP (port 80) traffic through the VPN, reducing latency somewhat;
- Set up an ad blocker. It is understood it's not working out of the box for you, because it's unlikely your ad blocker will have correct rules predefined for your particular ISP, but [you can refine those rules](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters).
- Get rid of this ISP in favor of a better one. This is the best possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, My ISP don't know about this issue and he is getting this issue too. He said they are coming from upper level and ignore them. Simply he can't control them. Now your suggestions 1. Not possible to use always HTTPS 2. That sound mouthful, I'll learn about it. 3. Ad Blocker are kind a problematic, they slow down websites and affects some of the scripts 4. I'll think about this after going through second advise. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @GauravSharma try also to spot from which Web site do those ads originate. E.g. right-click on an image and select "Show image", then look into the address bar. Is the site which is displayed there familiar to you? Does it look like an automatically generated one? If the answer to both questions is "no", then you can probably use either ad blocker or simply [a `hosts` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to block this particular site.

Comment: link attached with that ad: [link](http://codeforces.com/BIBgtzXLwfd_f6mPLRxfKYvPBh4vkf1JCKQ1uc0Qgb6KU5bWbeYKblfw5rlN7K4eF2BCV2_kQPkXSaVAffU=)

Comment: What's the name of your ISP?

Comment: It's actually a local provider.